# Error converting data type varchar to float

Tags: sql

I have the following SQL statement which is giving me this error.

"Error converting data type varchar to float" in this line

```
   ,  pe.ProductWeight + ' lb' AS weight
```

I realize this is wrong but I don't know how to add "lb" to the weight value. Any help would be appreciated.

```
SELECT p.ProductCode AS id

,  p.ProductName AS title

,  'Home & Garden > Household Appliance Accessories > Laundry Appliance Accessories' AS product_type

,  IsNull(pe.SalePrice,pe.ProductPrice) AS price

,  IsNull(pe.ProductManufacturer,'n/a') AS brand

,  IsNull(pe.ProductCondition,'new') AS condition

,  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), (GETDATE() + 30),120) AS expiration_date

,  pd.ProductDescriptionShort AS [stripHTML-description]

,  'http://www.thesite.com/v/vspfiles/photos/' + IsNull(p.Vendor_PartNo,p.ProductCode) + '-2.jpg' AS image_link

,  'http://www.thesite.asp?ProductCode=' + p.ProductCode + '&Click=1327'  AS link

,  pe.ProductWeight + ' lb' AS weight


FROM Products p

INNER JOIN Products_Descriptions pd ON p.ProductID = pd.ProductID

INNER JOIN Products_Extended pe ON pd.ProductID = pe.ProductID

WHERE (p.IsChildOfProductCode is NULL OR p.IsChildOfProductCode = ' AND (p.HideProduct is NULL OR p.HideProduct <> 'Y')

AND (pe.ProductPrice > 0)

ORDER BY p.ProductCode
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to concatenate a float and a string, you need to cast the float to a string first:

```
   CAST(pe.ProductWeight AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' lb' AS weight
```

Comment: LOL, seems pretty easy. Thx 20 would be the max length, correct?

Answer (score 1):

Varchar has lower precedence than float, so it is attempting to turn ' lb' into a float and failing.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx for ranking.